# How am I allowed to pass a void parameter through bash functions?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, bash-functions

I'm writing something like the following script. **It's doesn't work as expected because the function `deleteCEfromCeLst` has to call a script specifying to it a "void" parameter through the `spawnPrg` function**, but if I specify in the `spawnPrg` function parameters the "void" parameter `''`, that I use when I call the script `$HOME/execsh/delete.sh` directly from prompt,  this "void" parameter results (correctly) as nothing and not as a not specified parameter.

*The use of the `spawnPrg` function is mandatory because it will be used from other functions called from the "main" flow or directly by the main flow, furthermore the function `spawnPrg` shall contain behaviours act to register something like a log file.*

```
#!/bin/bash

spawnPrg()
{
    echo $@
    $@ &

    return
}

deleteCEfromCeLst()
{
    local d

    cat ce.lst | while read d; do           
        spawnPrg $HOME/execsh/delete.sh $1 '' $d
    done

    return
}

deleteCEfromCeLst
exit
```

I tried also to code `deleteCEfromCeLst` as:

```
deleteCEfromCeLst()
{
    local d

    cat ce.lst | while read d; do           
        spawnPrg "$HOME/execsh/delete.sh $1 '' $d"
    done

    return
}
```

With the above code the result is that the function spawnPrg is executed as it is sent to the prompt as:

```
$HOME/execsh/delete.sh $1 \'\' $d
```

where the "void" parameter is specified as the string `''` that is either that the second parameter sent to the `delete.sh` script is not a "void" parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote the variable expansions.

If we have a script `foo.sh`:

```
$ cat foo.sh 
#!/bin/sh
args() {
        printf ">%s<\n" "$@"
}
args "$1" "" foo
```

And we call it with `sh foo.sh ""`, the output is:

```
><
><
>foo<
```

That is, one empty argument from `"$1"` (the argument to `foo.sh`), another from the hard-coded `""` in the script, and then the fixed string `foo`.

If either of `$@` or `$1` would have been unquoted, the empty values in question would disappear as part of word splitting.

See:

- This wiki page on word splitting: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373)